# Ajax, prevent multiple request on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to prevent multiple requests when user click on login or register button. This is my code, but it doesn't work. Just the first time works fine, then return false..

```
$('#do-login').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( $(this).data('requestRunning') ) {
        return;
    }

    $(this).data('requestRunning', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            //stuffs
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
        }
    });      
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    complete: function() {
        $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
    }
```

`this` no longer points to the button.

```
$('#do-login').click(function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( me.data('requestRunning') ) {
        return;
    }

    me.data('requestRunning', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            //stuffs
        },
        complete: function() {
            me.data('requestRunning', false);
        }
    });      
});
```

Answer (score 44):

Use `on()` and `off()`, that's what they are there for :

```
$('#do-login').on('click', login);

function login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    that.off('click'); // remove handler
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize()
    }).done(function(msg) {
        // do stuff
    }).always(function() {
        that.on('click', login); // add handler back after ajax
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Joe's solution works fine. but this other way to get the same result. Which is the best solution?

Comment: @adeneo's solution is better.

Comment: @JoeFrambach - thanks, but it's a matter of preference really, there's nothing wrong with setting a flag in data(), but this does seem like just what on() and off() was meant to do, add and remove event handlers ?

Comment: What if: user click on button (so AJAX request is send) then click another time on it (and AJAX is still not complete) : e.preventDefault() wont be called so button will submit the form (while it should just do nothing)

Comment: @tigrou - yes, if it's a form, that could potentially happen, but it's easy to solve, just add preventDefault to the submit event handler.

Comment: It's important to make sure before reattaching the click event handler if it's really necessary. For example, if you are reloading the page after a successful response from the server, reattaching without checking anything could generate multiple requests.

Comment: I usually use `<button type="button">` instead of a submit button, that prevents submit of form accidentally.

Answer (score 6):

In your ajax callbacks the context (`this`) changes from the outer function, you can set it to be the same by using the context property in $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/auth/login.php",
    data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
    context: this, //<-----
    success: function(msg) {
        //stuffs
    },
    complete: function() {
        $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation of option `context`

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the button.

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced a similar problem.

Just adding `$('#do-login').attr("disabled", true);` gives me the solution.

```
$('#do-login').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#do-login').attr("disabled", true);
   .........
   .........
```

Here `do-login` is button id.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this and worked very fine for me, I was having trouble that $.ajax send more request until results return,

```
 var settings = {
    "url": "/php/auth/login.php",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "async": false,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "data": jsondata, //data pass here is in JSON format
};
$.ajax(settings).done(function (ress) {
  try{
      console.log(ress, "Result from Ajax here");
    }
    catch(error){
      alert(error);
      console.log(ress);
    }
});
```

`async : false` worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it by   `$(this).addClass("disabled");` to you button or link and after click is performed, you can   `$(this).removeClass("disabled");`.

// CSS

```
.disabled{
cursor: not-allowed;

}
```

// JQUERY

```
$('#do-login').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass("disabled");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        context: this,
        success: function(msg) {
    //do more here

           $(this).removeClass("disabled");
        },
    });
});
```

P.S. If you use bootstrap css, you do not need the css part.

Answer (score 0):

I found the approach useful. I've implemented it as a general purpose function for jQuery with ES6.

```javascript
export default function (button, promise) {
    const $button = $(button);
    const semaphore = 'requestRunning';

    if ($button.data(semaphore)) return null;
    $button.data(semaphore, true);

    return promise().always(() => {
        $button.data(semaphore, false);
    });
}
```

Because `$.ajax()` returns a promise, you simply pass in the promise and the function takes care of the rest.

Roughly speaking, here's the usage.

```javascript
import preventDoubleClick from './preventdoubleclick';

...

button.click(() => {
    preventDoubleClick(this, () => $.ajax()
        .done(() => { console.log("success") }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can help you with control multi Ajax requests and it's has timeout function which can return flag status to 0 after ex. 10sec (In case the server took more than 10 seconds to respond)

```
var Request_Controller = function(Request_Name = '', Reactivate_Timeout = 10000)
{
    var a = this;
    a.Start_Request = function(){
        if(window.Requests == undefined){
            window.Requests = {};
        }
        window.Requests[Request_Name] = {'Status' : 1, 'Time': + new Date()};
    }

    a.End_Request = function(){
        if(window.Requests == undefined){
            window.Requests = [];
        }
        window.Requests[Request_Name] = undefined;
    }

    a.Is_Request_Running = function(){
        if(window.Requests == undefined || window.Requests[Request_Name] == undefined){
            return 0;
        }else{
            var Time = + new Date();
            // Reactivate the request flag if server take more than 10 sec to respond
            if(window.Requests[Request_Name]['Time'] < (Time - Reactivate_Timeout)) 
            {
                return 0;
            }else{
                return 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var Request_Flag = new Request_Controller('Your_Request_Name');
if(!Request_Flag.Is_Request_Running()){

    Request_Flag.Start_Request();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            //stuffs
        },
        complete: function() {
            Request_Flag.End_Request();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score -9):

for prevent multiple ajax request in whole site. For example: If use ajax request in other ajax page, Using ajax in php loop, etc, Give you multiple ajax request with one result. I have solution:

```
Use window.onload = function() { ...  }
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ...  });
```

on the main index.php page. Its will be prevent all multi request. :)