# Using jQuery's off() and on() with an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to disable multiple clicks until an ajax request is complete.  I've seen solutions using global variables, but feel using `off` and `on` would be more elegant.  [Ajax, prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click) describes using `off` and `on`, but does so using a named function (as opposed to an anonymous function).  How can this be accomplished with an anonymous function?  If not possible, what is the best way to disable the event until the ajax request is complete?

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    //Remove anonymous  function
    $.post('delay.php',function(x) {
        console.log('done '+x);
        //Add back anonymous function
    })
});
```

Comment: be sure to re-enable the button using the complete callback rather than the success callback. Otherwise a temporary 500 error would prevent the user from trying again.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by the complete callback.

Comment: Using `on/off`seems a bit over-kill. Doesn't using an `active` class on the element suit you instead? If it's set, `return;`, otherwise add it and proceed with ajax request. On complete, remove the class.

Comment: @user1032531, [`$.ajax` has a "complete" option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), with `$.post` you'd chain the [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) function off of the deferred that's returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this code.

HTML:

```
<button id="button" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var that = this;
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    $.post('delay.php',function(x) {
        $(that).removeAttr("disabled");
        console.log('done '+x);
    })
});
```

Comment: I came up with something similar using `data`, but yours is probably better.