# How to avoid multiple AJAX requests to the same URL in a single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have call AJAX request in button click. When click button it’s calling two times in single click. How to avoid this?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkotp').click(function() {
    var otp = $("#otp").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>exchanges/check_otp',
      data: {
        "otp": otp
      },
      type: 'post',
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The below way AJAX calls:

[image]

Comment: is `#checkotp` a submit button for a form, perhaps? though, there's no reason why you you get a POST/GET/POST/GET from a single click in that code

Comment: no , its button tag  <button id="checkotp" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="check_otp">Check OTP</button>

Comment: is it inside a `<form>` - ahh, type="button" ... carry on :p

Comment: no, Just call onclick function

Comment: so, a single click results in `POST/GET/POST/GET` ... or just `POST/GET` ... you say *it’s calling two times* and post FOUR requests

Comment: yes sigle click call post/get , The above scren show two time clicked but ajax called 4 time

Comment: so, the form seems to be submitting ... can you show the form element please

Comment: try `.click(function(e) { e.prevendDefault(); ... rest of your handler ...`

Comment: i am not created form, geting values using id's in text box

Comment: so there's no `<form>` in your HTML ... OK

Comment: Ok i will try 2 mints

Comment: the $.ajax is a POST request, and you can see it's being called inside jquery ... the question remains, where the hell does the GET request come from? Is there a response header `Content-Type: application/javascript` by any chance?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? @shanmugakumar

Comment: Its not working

Comment: no, didn't think it would, I asked before I knew there was no `<form>` - what is in the response?

Comment: jQuery v1.12.4  @Johny

Comment: Okay, I will with form

Comment: change your type to method? From jQuery API "You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0." @shanmugakumar

Comment: The GET call is to a different file (it has `/en/`). Are you sure that the get call is not made inside the `check_otp` file? Can you show the content of that file?

Comment: The response to the first call has the HTTP status code `302`, which means that the second call is just a redirect.

Comment: Can you also post exchanges/check_otp code? Looks like there's a redirect happening somewhere...@shanmugakumar

Comment: @Titus - you cheated by reading the text in images :p

Comment: Not yet redirect any other page

Comment: @all Its working fine Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable button/link than check response from server.
please visit :
[Ajax, prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click)