# How to restrict multiple user logins at same time using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC Application using JavaScript, jQuery.

I have implemented to be restrict multiple user logins at same time using `onbeforeunload`/`beforeunloadevent`.

It works fine, but sometimes not working in `onbeforeunload`/`beforeunloadevent`.

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    if (!validNavigation)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ClearSession", "Account")',
            type: 'Post',
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data)
            {
                console.log("onbeforeunload Success")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("onbeforeunload Error")
            }
        });
    }

    return null;
});
```

Comment: By using same userid and password , you want to login multiple times or all time user and password is different.

Comment: If User Already login means and also same user try to login in diffrent browser means I need to restrict same user and password.

Comment: You cannot reliably assume that your ajax call will be called before leaving the page. If you're lucky the request will be created, but whether it'll go through before the browser navigates away (and kills the http connection) is most likely not going to happen. The best you can do is make a "last activity" and say "if the user has been active within the last 10 minutes, they cannot log back in". `beforeunload` would not execute either on power shortages, internet cutouts, crashes etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is one also function in `AJAX - jQuery` is called `complete: function(){};`
This `function` checks weather `request is running` for same user id and password on browser or not,  Like this here

```
complete: function() {
        $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
    }
```

Whole `AJAX-jQuery` implementation here see and implement accordingly, I hope it will work fine for you

**Code Here**

```
$('#do-login').click(function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( me.data('requestRunning') ) {
        return;
    }

    me.data('requestRunning', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            //stuffs
        },
        complete: function() {
            me.data('requestRunning', false);
        }
    });      
});
```

See this `me.data('requestRunning', false);` if it will get any request running for same user id and password it `returns false` and cancel login.

For more help see here link [Duplicate, Ajax prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click?answertab=active#tab-top)

This is not perfect solution but you can implement like this