# ajax click fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form with 2 buttons `save & continue` and `save and exit`. I have given these buttons 2 ids as well, namely `save_cont` and `save_exit` respectively.

The first button works fine but when I click the second button, the ajax of first button fires as well and as a result, I'm unable to redirect my url and the page reloads.

Inside demo.discount.blade.php:

```
//Save and Continue
$('#save_cont').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'demo_save_data',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#add_seasonal_discount").serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.success > 0) {
                alert("Save and Continue");
                window.location.reload();
            }

        }
    });

});

//Save and Exit
$('#save_exit').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'demo_save_data',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#add_seasonal_discount").serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.success > 0) {
                alert("Save and Exit");
                window.location = 'demo_seasonal_discount_newpage_report.php';
            }

        }
    });

});
$("#save_cont").unbind("click");
```

HTML of buttons:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 required">
    <button title="Save" id="save_cont" class="scl_issave a-link btn scl-btn-clasic scl-btn-margin-v" type="button">Save & Continue</button>
    <button title="Save" id="save_exit" class="scl_issave_exit a-link btn scl-btn-clasic scl-btn-margin-v" type="button">Save & Exit</button>
</div>
```

Inside my controller:

```
public function demo_save_data() {
    DB::table('demo_table') ->
        insert([
            'invoice_type' => Input::get('invoice_type'),
            'sales_channel' => Input::get('pricing_group'),
            'material' => Input::get('matnr'),
            'from_date' => Input::get('fromdt'),
            'to_date' => Input::get('todt'),
            'discount' => Input::get('discount'),
            'bukrs' => Session::get('company')
        ]);

    return array('success' => 1);
}
```

EDIT: added `$("#save_cont").unbind("click");`, at the end. Now the second button `save_exit` works fine, but the first button `save_cont` doesn't work at all.

Comment: made the requested edits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax, prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click)

Comment: I've the feeling your observation regarding first ajax request beeing send is wrong. Maybe that's just some kind of redirection done server side. How do you check that first click event is fired?

Comment: I added this code at the end of the second button's ajax: $("#save_cont").unbind("click"); Now, the second button works fine but the first button doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see at a glance why the behavior you describe would happen.  You can consolidate them into a single function and eliminate the problem though, since you are sending same data to same place, like:

```
 function thingClicked(theThing){
   $.ajax({
     url:'demo_save_data',
     type:'POST',
     data:$("#add_seasonal_discount").serialize(),
     success:function(result){
       if(result.success>0){
         if(theThing == 'save_cont'){
           alert("Save and Continue");
           window.location.reload();
         }else if(theThing == 'save_exit'){
           alert("Save and Exit");
           window.location='demo_seasonal_discount_newpage_report.php';
         }
       }  
     });
  }
```

then of course you can call it however you like.  The `.click()` binding you use should be fine...

```
$("#save_cont").click(thingClicked(this.id));
```

and

```
$("#save_exit").click(thingClicked(this.id));
```

nothing really changed but the only difference between the two is the return so may as well put the conditional logic there, and eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: Tried the above, yet the result is same. #save_cont runs normally but save_exit runs twice i.e. first it alerts ("Save and Exit") and then ("Save and Continue")