# Getting 2 ajax requests from 1 click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm writing an application that uses the ajax functionality provided by jquery 3.2.1.

I'm expericning a problem where when I click on a link **once** it is generating two ajax requests - I can see these in the Network tab of my browser.

The click happens on a hyperlink with an ID of `removeAllFiltersBtn`:

```
<a href="/remove-filter/all" id="removeAllFiltersBtn">remove all filters</a>
```

I have the following for the ajax call:

```
$('#removeAllFiltersBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        method: 'get'
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (response.result === 'all_filters_removed') {
            $('.filters-panel').hide();
        } 
        if (response.n_filters === 0) {
            $('.filters-panel').hide();
        }
    }).done(function () { 
        debouncedDraw();
    });
});
```

I've read [Ajax, prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click) and tried the following:

1. Adding `return false` to the end of the function.
2. Adding `$(this).prop('disabled', true);` to disable the button. I put this just before `$.ajax({ ...`

The function inside `.done` called `debouncedDraw();` runs another function that updates a table. The request for this happens after the ajax request above and is called `/search`. So in my Network tab I see:

[image]

Why are there 2 requests to `/remove-filter/all` and how can I make it just 1 request?

I've read up on Promises but am not sure if that's relevant to the problem I'm experiencing. Please can someone explain this in simple terms?

Comment: Check how many events you have on that element #removeAllFiltersBtn

Comment: Thanks, you've shown me the problem and I would not have got it otherwise. There are 2 separate handlers on the anchors inside a `<div>` that fire that ajax request! Thank you.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue, but mine doesn't happen to just one element, it happens on all ajax calls via a click event. It makes two identical ajax requests, I can't figure out why.

Comment: @EricMcWinNEr it's likely the same issue. Basically you need to figure out all the events that could potentially trigger the ajax call. In my case I had a `<div>` with a class `.filters-panel`. It turned out that in my code I'd already written something that acted on any `<a>` tags inside `<div class="filters-panel">`. Then I introduced a button inside that same div and was targeting it with a second lot of code. I hadn't remembered about the first set. So anything clicked inside `.filters-panel` ran 2 sets of code, so made 2 ajax calls. I bet it'll be something similar.