# Why every next ajax call multiplied by the times it have been called before?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope that I'm clear with my problem, if not screenshot would clearify it.

A simple form I have:

```
    <div class="container player-demo" id="player-wrap">
        <form method="post"> 
            <textarea id="dataText" class="data-text" placeholder="Type your message here!"></textarea>
            <div id="player"></div>
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="call-btn" id="trigger" disabled>GET VOICE</button>
                <button type="button" class="call-btn" id="load" disabled>SENDING</button>
                <button type="button" id="play-btn" onclick="playAudio()"> PLAY </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My JS code. It's a little bit mess but still working :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataText').keyup(e => {
        $('#trigger').removeAttr('disabled');
        $listen.show();
        $play.hide();
        // console.log(e.target.value); 
    }); 
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var textdata = $('#dataText').val();
            var postData = textdata; 
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "https://voicerss-text-to-speech.p.rapidapi.com/?",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "",
                    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "voicerss-text-to-speech.p.rapidapi.com"
                },
                data: {
                    src: postData,
                    hl: "en-us",
                    r: "0",
                    c: "mp3",
                    f: "8khz_8bit_mono",
                    b64: true
                },   
            }).done(function (response) {
                $('#player').html(`<audio id="myAudio"><source src=${response}></audio>`);
                // $('#controls').html(`<button type="button" onclick="playAudio()"> PLAY </button>`);     
                
            });
            $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $listen.hide();
                $loading.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $loading.hide();
                $listen.hide();
                $play.show();
            });
            console.log(postData);
        });
    });
});

var $loading = $('#load').hide();
var $listen = $('#trigger');
var $play = $('#play-btn').hide();

function playAudio() {
let myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
myAudio.play();
}
```

So every time I submit my request, it comes back sends multipled request.
I'm not sure, but I think this bug related to event handler. I've tried to remove it, but failed.
Maybe my hole JS code is not organised well, so it's difficult to do correctly.
I want undestand logic behind the process, but right now it's a dark place for me.
Please help! :)

[This what I get in console.]
 [console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8gig.jpg)

Comment: You have nested events, so every time you click #trigger you get *another* form.submit handler.  Don't nest events.

Comment: In your case *either* remove the line `$('#trigger').click(function() {` (and corresponding `})` ofc) so your ajax calls when the form submits *or* remove the line `$('form').submit(function(e) {` (and `})`) so that your ajax calls whenever you click the button.

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click

Comment: Thanks guy! DO NOT nest events is very helpful lesson!